# How to start testing database with data after schema design?

Tags: sql, database-design

This is a newbie question. My last (and only SQL) online database that I created 10 years ago for a small ASP.NET application, had only a few tables with some user settings. That's it. All the other databases I've ever done were with Access. I am now creating a full-blown .NET application with an SQL database that will manage my entire company (orders, employees, payrolls, taxes, customer care, etc). For now it will be a local DB and I will be the only one managing it and inputting data (this may change in the future).

My company is not huge but I do have about 100 clients, some employees, and thousands of rows of past years data that will eventually go into the databse. We also provide different kinds of services so this DB schema wasn't simple for me as I had to overcome challenges. I just completed the schema with 60 tables and weeks of research and asking questions.

I did a backup of the current schema via SQL backup and also it's script so I have a .sql file and a .bak file (scared I'll mess something up).

Now it's time to test the database and this is where I can't find the correct way to do so. Of course I'm not comparing Access to SQL but the workflow of testing in Access was very simple since I use the GUI by simply dragging out the tables into a form and Access would make all the relationships connect (if dragged out correctly) and you have a complete GUI with text boxes, comboboxes, etc, where needed - all ready to start entering data as you wish - and see where you get errors.

With SQL I keep seeing how people are generating test data via queries and this seems impossible to do since I have children of children of children (and more) and can't see how it's possible to know what the surrogate PKs would be in order to enter correct FKs... would you have to go back and forth between the tables and look these up? Seems tedious and probably not the way it's done.

So now I sit back and look at my first big schema (with some pride :-) ) and yes, knowing of course I probably made some mistakes, but don't know how to start testing it with data in every table.

I will do all the reading but just need a little "shove" in the right direction where this is explained. Couldn't find it anywhere but that's probably because I wasn't looking for the right thing.

(screenshot is not for reading... just to give you a "big-picture")

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't expect to build and test the database independently of the application. Create some integration tests against the application code.

Comment: I'm SO happy to hear that. I didn't even start the application code yet. So it's ok to bring the database into a new application, make codes, forms, classes, sql queries, controls, etc... and test data input there?

Comment: At some point you ought to create test data in bulk and it may be beneficial to do that outside the application but if the application isn't built yet then I would start on that first. The database can't be considered "done" until you've tested the end-to-end solution that uses it. You are bound to discover things you need to change about the database.